# How to retrieve email address from user ID?

Tags: 2010, development, event-receivers

I'm developing an Event Receiver in C# and I would like to retrieve the email address from a user ID.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string Email = properties.Web.AllUsers.GetByID(userID).Email;
```

Comment: Does it require UPS or will it work without UPS?

Answer (score 1):

Get the userfieldvalue and then get the email from it using below code:

```
SPFieldUserValue userName = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, userID);
string userEmail=userName.User.Email;
```